# Is there a way to put calculated column in ALL()?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to remove filters from a calculated column with `ALL()`, and the measure seems to ignore it

[image: Example for the visual]

"Class" is a calculated column.
I want to add measure always showing 100 (the grand total)
There are outer filters on the table so I don't want to use `ALL(TABLE)`
However, `CALCULATE(SUM([Total Sales]), ALL(Product, Class))` doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work how?  Are you getting an error or just an unexpected result?  I ask because your code looks like it's going in the proper direction given what you've asked -- to sum [Total Sales] ignoring filters on [product] and [class] while preserving all other filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ALL()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) on a list of columns like this:

```
CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Sales] ), ALL ( Table1[Product], Table1[Class] ) )
```

This should work fine even if `Class` is a calculated column.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried exactly that and it doesn't work

Comment: Your syntax was questionable, so I thought that may have been the issue. What error are you getting?

Comment: No error, the results just stay the same whether I put "Class" in ALL or don't

Comment: If there are other columns in the table, they can affect the row context of your calculated column. I recommend using `ALLEXCEPT( Table1, [list of columns you want to preserve row context] )` instead of `ALL( [list of columns you want to remove from row context] )`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will work however I have multiple filters and columns etc. I was hoping to avoid to write such an explicit ALLEXCEPT

Comment: You can pick either `ALL` or `ALLEXCEPT` depending on what makes more sense in your context, but the latter is a bit safer (in case you add more columns later) and less likely to cause circular dependency errors.